# How to post data from an EXCEL Userform to a Google form with a spreadsheet at the backend?

Tags: excel, http, vba, google-docs

I have a problem that I've been looking to solve, but so far no one has been able to help me.

I have an excel file, that I will distribute amongst colleagues. They will open it, and enter 5 fields:-

Name, 
Delivery Address, 
Cell Phone Number, 
Email Address, and 
Amount Payable.

Once done, they will verify the values that will be displayed in a filled userform (i.e. values will be picked from the excel cells that have been filled).

I want that once the submit button is clicked, the userform uses a POST function to populate the spreadsheet that is available at my google docs page.

Now I know that this is possible, since people have been accessing the google form via a POST function.
See here:
 http://asynclabs.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=489

Could somebody be kind enough to help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to research the Google Spreadsheets API http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/ Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do a HTTP POST from Excel VBA is probably to use `MSXML`.

Add a reference to "Microsoft XML, v3.0", use like the following example VBA code:

```
Dim httpRequest as XMLHTTP
Set httpRequest = New XMLHTTP

' ... False means execute request synchronously
httpRequest.Open "POST", "https://spreadsheets.google.com/...", False
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
httpRequest.send "entry.0.single=<DATA1>&..."

' ... after the .send call finishes, you can check the server's response:
httpRequest.status
httpRequest.statusText
httpRequest.responseText
httpRequest.responseXML
```

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)